# Failed to compile. ./src/app/app.module.ts .Module not found: Error: Empty dependency (no request)

Tags: angular

I am getting this error when I am trying to add RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes) line in my app.module.ts. 
Below are my app.module.ts file

app.module.ts file.

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {RouterModule} from '';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
import { AboutComponent } from './about/about.component';
import { CoursesComponent } from './courses/courses.component';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
 {path:'',component:HeaderComponent},
 {path:'about',component:AboutComponent},
 {path:'courses',component:CoursesComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
  AppComponent,
  HeaderComponent,
  AboutComponent,
  CoursesComponent
 ],
imports: [
  BrowserModule,
  FormsModule,
  RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
],
providers: [],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason of this error is in your imports of `RouterModule` you didn't specify the path of this module. take a look at your imports.

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
```

> import {RouterModule} from '';

```
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
import { AboutComponent } from './about/about.component';
import { CoursesComponent } from './courses/courses.component';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';
```